# Gigabit NIC only connecting at 100Mbps

Tags: networking, network-adapter

We have a desktop PC in a field office that only connects to the network at 100Mbps even though the GB card seems to be functioning perfectly. We have plugged in other machines into the same jack and they connect at 1Gbps. Of course, when the network guys saw that, they washed their hands of the issue. Could there be some setting (or combination of settings) that could cap the connection at 100Mbps?

Comment: Are you sure the link-speed on that PC's NIC isn't hard-set (in the OS) to 100Mbps?  If you manually hard-set it to 1Gbps, does it link at 1Gb?

Answer (score 3):

Have you physically verified there is a gigabit NIC in this desktop PC?

Gigabit NICs support 100Mbps and 10Mpbs standards, and you can typically configure a card to use a lower speed in its driver options on Windows.  Some NIC drivers also have power management/saving options that lower the speed to consume less power.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling the NIC drivers (assuming Windows) to reset these options.

A defective cable, defective connector, missing pin in the NICs jack, or a network cable with missing wires (gigabit needs all 8) may also cause only a lower speed to be supported.